# transition from one base to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Given the polynomials $p_1,p_2,p_3,v_1,v_2,v_3 \in P_2$:
>   \begin{gather*}
> p_1(t) := t^2 − 2t + 5, \qquad
> p_2(t) := 2t^2 − 3t, \qquad
> p_3(t) := t + 1, \\
> v_1(t) := t^2 + 4t − 3, \qquad
> v_2(t) := t − 1, \qquad
> v_3(t) := 1.
> \end{gather*}
>   find the matrix of transition from base $P=\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ to base $V = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$.

I have found the matrix:
$$
M_1 := \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -6 & 2 \\
2 & - 11 & -5 \\
0 & 1 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and I thought that this is the answer because
\begin{gather*}
p_1(t) = v_1(t) − 6 v_2(t) + 2 v_3(t), \qquad
p_2(t) = 2 v_1(t) − 11 v_2(t) − 5 v_3(t), \quad
p_3(t) = 0 \cdot v_1(t) + 1 \cdot v_2(t) + 2 v_3(t).
\end{gather*}
but it turns out that I should find matrix like this:
$$
M_2 := \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
-6 & -11 & 1 \\
2 & -5 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and after that to find a matrix of transition i should find inverse matrix from that matrix so i would get matrix like this:
$$
\frac{1}{11}
\begin{pmatrix}
-17 & -4 & 2 \\
14 & 2 & -1 \\
52 & 9 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Can you please explain why

1. Why I had to find the matrix $M_2$ and not $M_1$, which is actually 
   transposed matrix $M_2$.
2. Why I had to find the inverse matrix $M_2$, (why is the inverse matrix of $M_2$ matrix of transition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $M_1$ is the correct matrix if you have a polynomial expressed in terms of the $v$s and you want it expressed in terms of the $p$s and if your polynomials are column vectors.  If I have a polynomial $av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ and express it as a column matrix $\begin {pmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{pmatrix}$ I can premultiply it by $M_1$ and get the polynomial expressed in terms of the $p$s.  You needed to transpose it because you presumably use row vectors, so the polynomial would be expressed by the matrix $\begin {pmatrix}a&b&c \end{pmatrix}$ and postmultiplied by $M_2$, giving a new row vector.

The reason you needed to invert it is that you were asked to start with $p$s and get $v$s.  If you had written $v_1=$an expression of $p$'s you would have gotten the right matrix at the start.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $M_1$ is the transition from $V$ to $P$. You take the vectors in $V$, you apply the transformation $M_1$ and you get the vectors in $P$